# What information must be removed from judicial decisions in France when made public?

Tags: privacy, france

According to (1), anyone in France may ask for a copy of a judicial decision. If one decides to make it available publicly, e.g. on a website, the [National Commission on Informatics and Liberty (CNIL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commission_nationale_de_l%27informatique_et_des_libert%C3%A9s) demand to be de-identified (2). What information must be removed from judicial decisions in France when made public?

I am looking for an exhaustive list, such as the list defined by the [Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act (HIPAA) rules](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/understanding/coveredentities/De-identification/guidance.html) in the United States that list all types of information that must be removed from a patient note before it can be shared publicly:

```
(i) Names of patients and family members
(ii) Addresses and their components
(iii) Dates (month and day parts, unless the inclusion of the year part identities an individual to be older than 90 years old)
(iv) Explicit mention of ages over 89 years old
(v) Telephone and fax numbers
(vi) Social Security numbers
(vii) Medical record numbers
(viii) Health plan beneficiary numbers
(ix) Account numbers
(x) Certificate or license numbers
(xi) Vehicle identifiers and serial numbers
(xii) Device identifers and serial numbers
(xiii) Electronic mail addresses
(xiv) Web universal resource locators (URLs)
(xv) Internet protocol (IP) addresses
(xvi) Biometric identifiers
(xvii) Full face photographic images
(xviii) Employers
(xix) Any other unique identifying number, characteristic or code
```

---

- (1) http://www.precisement.org/blog/Se-procurer-la-copie-d-une-decision-de-justice-les-bases-legales-et-un-guide.html:

  > Les tiers – personnes qui ne sont pas parties à la décision [7] – peuvent donc se faire délivrer copie des décisions qui ont été prononcées publiquement, ou plus exactement que l’on considère comme telles. 
  >   Gtranslate: The third-parties, i.e. persons who are not parties to the decision, can therefore be given copies of the decisions that have been spoken publicly , or more precisely that we consider as such.
- (2) http://www.droit-technologie.org/actuality-498/la-publication-des-decisions-de-justice-sur-l-internet.html

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, France is internationally know for having some of the most bare bones judicial decisions in the world that typically state the bare minimum to loosely suggest a reason for the decision and to convey the ultimate legal conclusion that the court reached.

A case that would typically be resolved with a judicial opinion of thirty to fifty pages full of factual detail and legal reasoning in a court in Britain or the United States, would frequently be resolved when identical facts and legal issues are presented with a three to five page decision in France.

So, often only monetary amounts, account numbers, and some proper names (at least of people other than parties to the case) would have to be redacted from a decision, and sometimes not even that.